# how to make ncurses program working with other linux utils?

Tags: c, pipe, ncurses, curses

Suppose I have a ncurses program which does some job on curses screen, and finally print something to `stdout`. Call this program `c.c`, compiled to `a.out`.

I expect `cat $(./a.out)` first fire up ncurses, after some action, `a.out` quits and print `c.c` to `stdout`, which is read by `cat`, and thus print content of file `c.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    printw("hello world");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    fprintf(stdout, "c.c");
    return 0;
}
```

I also expect `./a.out | xargs vim`, `ls | ./a.out | xargs less` to work.

But when I type `./a.out | xargs vim`, `hello world` never shows up. The command seems not executed in order, vim does not open `c.c`.

What is the correct way to make a ncurses program to work with other linux utils?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes use the standard output (stdout) and standard input (stdin).

The simplest way - rather than using `initscr`, which initializes the output to use the *standard output*, use `newterm`, which allows you to choose the file descriptors, e.g.,

```
newterm(NULL, stderr, stdin);
```

rather than

```
initscr();
```

which is (almost) the same as

```
newterm(NULL, stdout, stdin);
```

By the way, when you include `<ncurses.h>` (or `<curses.h>`), there is no need to include `<stdio.h>`.

If you wanted to use your program in the *middle* of a pipe, that is more complicated: you would have to drain the standard input and open the actual terminal device.  But that's another question (and has already been answered).

Further reading:

- [**`initscr`**, **`newterm`**, **`endwin`**, **`isendwin`**, **`set_term`**, **`delscreen`** -
     ***curses*** screen initialization and manipulation routines](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html)

Answer (score 1):

`ncurses` works by writing a bunch of ansi escapes to stdout, which the terminal will interpret. You can run `./a.out > file` and then inspect the file to see what you're *actually* writing. It'll be immediately obvious why programs are confused:

```
$ cat -vE file
^[(B^[)0^[[?1049h^[[1;24r^[[m^O^[[4l^[[H^[[Jhello world^[[24;1H^[[?1049l^M^[[?1l^[>c.c
```

The correct way of doing this is to skip all the graphical/textual UI parts when you detect that stdout is not a terminal, i.e. it's consumed by a program instead of a user:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
  if(isatty(1)) {
    // Output is a terminal. Show stuff to the user.
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    printw("hello world");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
  } else {
    // Output is consumed by a program.
    // Skip UI.
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "c.c");
  return 0;
}
```

This is the canonical Unix behavior.

If you instead want to force your UI to be shown regardless, you can [draw your UI on stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286618/1899640).

Comment: [newterm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/curs_initscr.3x.html) is the usual solution.