# How do I pass the output of a c program which use curses/ncurses to another program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ncurses, curses

I have a simple c program which use `ncurses` to display some text on the screen. When running, it will print out `hello`, when the user press the arrow key up, it will exit the program printing on screen `bye see you soon`.

I would like to be able to use the output printed by the program, in this case `bye see you soon` as input of another program, for instance I would like to pass it to `grep` or `cat`, like:

```
./main.out | grep "bye"
```

similarly of the result I would get if I could pipe it like `echo "bye see you soon" | grep "bye"`

or alternatively by using something like command substitution `$(...)`.

With my current solution, if I use `./main.out | grep "bye"` I get always a blank screen and I am not able to pipe to grep.

Currently looking to a solution for Linux/macOS only.

I would like to know:

- How I could solve this problem? (I would appreciate a snippet of code)
- Is `atexit` the only solution available?

I am learning a bit of c, if you are able to give me a bit more context in the answer I would really appreciate it.

Run the program with:

```
make all
./main.out
```

```
================================== main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_menu(WINDOW *menu_win);

void bye(void)
{
    printf("bye see you soon\n");
}

void print_menu(WINDOW *menu_win)
{
    printf("hi");
    wrefresh(menu_win);
}

int main()
{
    WINDOW *menu_win;
    int c;

    initscr();
    clear();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    menu_win = newwin(30, 30, 0, 0);
    keypad(menu_win, TRUE);
    refresh();
    print_menu(menu_win);
    
    while (1)
    {
        c = wgetch(menu_win);
        switch (c)
        {
        case KEY_UP:
            endwin();

            int i = atexit(bye);
            if (i != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "cannot set exit function\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        default:
            refresh();
            break;
        }
    }
    clrtoeol();
    refresh();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

```
================================== Makefile

SHELL   = /bin/sh
PROGRAM = main
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -O0 -Wall -Werror
LIBS    = -lncurses

all:
    $(CC) ./${PROGRAM}.c -o ./${PROGRAM}.out $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Might be able to use the Linux registers somehow?

Comment: You could use `isatty()` to check if `fileno(stdin)` is connected to a terminal. If it is, run with `curses`, if it's not, run in plain text mode.

Comment: This answers your question: [how to make ncurses program working with other linux utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283690/how-to-make-ncurses-program-working-with-other-linux-utils)

Comment: thanks for sharing very useful indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initscr` does the equivalent of `newterm(NULL, stdout, stdin)`, which pretty well makes it impossible to also pipe output into some other utility. If you want to do both, you can force ncurses to use `/dev/tty` for both input and output by replacing `initscr()` with something like:

```c
    FILE* tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "r+");
    SCREEN* screen = newterm(NULL, tty, tty);
    set_term(screen);
```

If you do that, you'll want to avoid writing to stdout (if it hasn't been redirected) while ncurses is active, since ncurses assumes that no-one else is writing to the console.

It might be useful to change the behaviour of your application, depending on whether `stdout` has been redirected. You could use `isatty()` for a fairly conservative test.

I don't really understand why you think it is necessary to use `atexit()` in your sample program. As soon as you call `endwin()`, it's safe to write to `stdout`. (But the `printf` of `Hi` in `print_menu` is problematic.)

It's also possible to use `stderr` as the ncurses output, on the assumption that it has not been redirected. I prefer the use of `/dev/tty` because it doesn't interfere with the use of `stderr` for error logging (invalidating the assumption that it has not been redirected). But if that's not important to you, `newterm(NULL, stderr, stdin)` is possibly simpler.

In any case, make sure you always check return values for error indications (which I omitted in the above code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, programs that use ncurses (or the older curses) don't output anything to stdout -- they only ever use stdin (and actually *write* to stdin to write to the terminal).  So they don't "play nice" with pipes that take the stdout of one process and connect it to the stdin of another process.

If you want to have a program that interacts with a terminal on stdin with ncurses and outputs something to stdout, you can do that -- stdin and stdout don't need to have anything to do with each other -- and that would allow you to pipe the output from stdout somewhere else.

Comment: thanks, not sure if I understand your point, am I not doing this already by using `printf` before the program exit? Would you able to provide modify my code showing the solution you have in mind? Thanks again

Comment: Assuming you use `initscr`, ncurses reads from stdin and writes to stdout. It's been like that a long time. Maybe that's not what you meant, though.